# Concavity of $f(k,r)=Ak-r$

Tags: calculus, geometry, self-learning

I have the following function $f(k,r)=Ak-r$ where $A>0$  is a constant

Is this function not concave in $(k,r)$? This is just linear. Right?

Comment: It is linear, convex and concave.

Answer (score 0):

It is linear, but also concave. Linear functions are always concave (and also convex); try verifying this from the definition of concave. However, it is not *strictly concave*.

Comment: Hmm I understand. Well can you please prove how it is concave ? Thank you.

Comment: Both convex and concave? How is it possible?

Comment: Concave essenrially means that if $0\le \theta \le 1$ and $k,r,I'd,r'\in \Bbb{R}$, then $A(\theta(k,r)+(1-\theta)(k',r')) \ge \theta A(k,r) + (1-\theta)A(k',r')$. So try showing this inequality. In fact, you should find that it holds with equality.

Comment: Both concave and convex means the above inequality holds both with $\le$ and $\ge$ (i.e. it is an equality). Note that since the inequalities in definition of convex and concave are *weak* inequalities ($\le$ or $\ge$), it is possible for both to hold.

Comment: Thank all you!!